# How to add cookies in iPAD safari browser?

Tags: ios

I would like to add new cookie in the iPAD safari browser but could not find a way. I would like to have similar thing like "Edit this cookie" browser addon for chrome.

Is there any possibility to drop cookie in safari ipad browser?

Comment: If you intent do this with a app then no, this is not possible since apps are sandboxed and can't interact with other apps. In iOS 8 this will change you can write plugins called [`App Extensions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214), you could write on for Safari.